# isolated high voltage H-bridge

Tags: transistors, analog, opto-isolator, mosfet-driver

I want to control on isolated  H bridge  that powered with 100V and can drive up to 0.5A low frequency 3HZ but Pulse width of 200uS .
the response times should be is US so i cant use Solid State Relay (Photo MOSFET).
I tried to use photo transistor like [this MOCD217M](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MO/MOCD217M.pdf) but the current is low (not passing 150mA).

please see below this Sample circuit that work at low voltages.

[image: isolated H bridge]

I ask:

1. what changes can be done  to match it to 100V?(VGS driving problem)
2. Is there any other  Simplified way to achieve the goal?

Thanks
Aharon

Comment: Have a look at the voltage that is applied between Gate and Source of each of the MOSFETs.  Then look at the datasheets for those devices and compare the voltage that you are applying to the maximum rated voltage as shown in the datasheets.  Do you see a problem there?

Comment: Next, estimate the RC time constant formed by the 10k pullup resistors and the gate capacitance of the MOSFETs.  Try to visualize what happens to the MOSFETs while the gate voltage is transitioning from LOW to HI.  Hint: both MOSFETs are turned ON at the same time during that time period.

Comment: Your bridge will self-destruct, for the reasons that Dwayne pointed out. That circuit will violate the maximum gate voltage for any Vcc over 20 volts. One solution is to implement what you have at the bottom on the N-FETs with two more optos on the P-FETs, thus separating the upper and lower half. Protection zeners on the gates would be a good idea. With you now being able to control each FET individually, you can address the "shoot-through" issue that Dwayne mentioned by adding dead-time.

Comment: Thanks  friends  looks great. i have one more  question: what is the best way to return as feedback the H bridge  measured currant optically?

Answer (score 1):

As you've realized, driving a gate with 100 volts is not a great idea. Neither is trying to switch 100 volts with an optocoupler with a maximum collector-emitter voltage of 70 volts (see page 3 of the data sheet). Input-output isolation voltage is NOT output operating voltage.

Dwayne Reid has also pointed out the folly of your schematic due to what's called "shoot-thru" current, which occurs when both the upper and lower transistors on one side are both turned on.

A basic approach might look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frPwhc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You'll need some logic to insert delays into the optocouplers so that you don't get shoot-thru, but since you've got separate optocouplers you should be able to do that without too much fuss.

Do note that if there is no optocoupler drive you'll burn out the FETs (or at least drive the 100 volt supply into current limit), so you'll need to be careful of your board interlocks.

Comment: Thanks  friends  looks great. i have one more  question: what is the best way to return as feedback the H bridge  measured currant optically?